# How use money format in pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am using this code. It returns the `sum()` of price and shows it with delimiter like money format

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST( sum(unitprice)  AS MONEY), 1), '.00', '')
FROM
    tchargecard_factor
GROUP BY 
    datetimeentry
```

and it works fine.

Please tell me how can I get this result from pivot table?

My code is :

```
'SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') AS [Grand Total] 
 INTO #temp_MatchesTotal
 FROM
     (SELECT 
          idpoint, [last mendub name], pointsalename, 
          agentname, mobile, remain, typegroupname
      FROM  
          zomorod_webapp_temp.dbo.chargecard_sum_typegroup4) A
 PIVOT
     (SUM(remain)
         FOR typegroupname IN ('  +@columnHeaders +  ')) B
 ORDER BY  
     idpoint
```

When I use this code, it is not allowing me to use cast or convert type in  `sum(remain)`. I get this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   'REPLACE' is not a recognized aggregate function

How can I fix it?

Comment: its give me this error :  Msg 195, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
'REPLACE' is not a recognized aggregate function.

Comment: I don't suggest using the `money` datatype at all. It's an inaccurate datatype, and has rounding issues.Store your data as a `decimal` and if you need to display it in a specific currency format (for example `$1000`, `£99,000.01`, `101,01€`) handle that in your presentation layer.

Comment: What are the values of `@GrandTotalCol` and `@columnHeaders`?

Comment: So essentially all you seem to want to do is to convert your numerical values into strings, and to lop off ".00", so 1.23 would become "1.23" and 1.00 would become "1"?  if this is the case then I would leave the `PIVOT` well alone and either do this in the presentation layer, as a separate update after you get the data into your temporary table, or by making the original query into a CTE/ subquery and then performing the logic before pushing the data into the final destination.

Comment: I said delimiter like money not money type.

Comment: and i must use and need pivot table for my work . the things is i need the numeric resault change to numeric with delimiter . but sum() function not allow me to change it . how i fix it ?

Comment: Please edit your question adding sample data in text format (no images)